# file_exists() not working as expected

Tags: php, file-exists

In the code below, `file_exists()` is not working as expected. Even when I'm trying to upload the same file, the else part gets executed. (ie `file_exists()` returns `false` in every case.) What is the reason behind this behavior?

```
if (isset($_FILES['file']['name']) && isset($_FILES['file']['size']) && isset($_FILES['file']['type']) && isset($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']))
{
    if (!empty($_FILES['file']['name']) && strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION))=='jpg' || strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION))=='jpeg')
    {
        if(file_exists($_FILES['file']['name']))
        {
           echo 'file exists';
        }
        else
        {
           move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'Images/'.$_FILES['file']['name']);

           echo $_FILES['file']['name'].' Uploaded'.'<br>';
        }
     }
}
else{ 
     echo 'select your file';
    }
```

Comment: `'Images/'.$_FILES['file']['name']` - that's the location you move the file to, but you test only `$_FILES['file']['name']`  (and keep in mind that information is provided by the client, it can be almost _any_ string)

Comment: @VolkerK thanks! working absolutely fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The problem

When you use `file_exists`, you only use the short name of the file.

```
if(file_exists($_FILES['file']['name']))
```

For example, if you upload a file called `test.jpg`, it checks if `./test.jpg` exists.

But, when you actually move the uploaded file, you put it in a directory called `Images`:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'Images/'.$_FILES['file']['name']);
```

Now, if you upload that `test.jpg`, it's moved to `./Images/test.jpg`, which isn't found by your other code.

#### The solution

You should use the same file name in both cases. So, just change the `if` with the `file_exists` call to:

```
if(file_exists('Images/'.$_FILES['file']['name']))
```

This code adds the folder name to the file name, so that you check for the correct path; uploading `test.jpg` leads to checking the file `./Images/test.jpg`.

Answer (score 0):

`$_FILES['file']['name']` is your INPUT / POST data, not your real file;

You should check `$your_dir_path_to_file . '/'.$_FILES['file']['name']`

Answer (score 0):

Set up the default file system separator (system dependent):

```
defined('DS') ? null : define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

If you can, try using absolute path not a relative one and secure the system from names like "../../file.jpg":

```
defined('BASE_PATH') ? null :  define('BASE_PATH', 'C:'.DS.'www'.DS.'Images'.DS);
```